# Bing Search API sample code not working

Tags: c#, bing-api

Has anyone got the Bing API C# Sample code working?  I am referring the Web Examples on this page: https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04

I'm also using the BingSearchContainer.cs file

```
string rootUri = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";

var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUri));

var accountKey = "Zasjkdhfkajshdfkjhasdkfjhetc";

bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);

// Build the query:
// Example says "var webQuery = .... I just tried this
DataServiceQuery<WebResult> webQuery = bingContainer.Web("Testing", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

// This returns a 403
// Example says "var results = .... I just tried this too...
IEnumerable<WebResult> results = webQuery.Execute();
```

I also tried things like:

```
bingContainer.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
```

... but that made no difference...

Thank you.

Comment: what is the error? what is not "working"? Perhaps you need a valid account key.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

have you subscribed for using the bing api ? please check the following link and subscribe as per your requirement

https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44